# How to remove multiple selected position item from adapter in android

Tags: android, kotlin

```
override fun removeDataAtPosition(listOfDeleteItemPosition: ArrayList<Int>) {
        for (i in listOfDeleteItemPosition.indices) {
            items.removeAt(i)
            notifyItemRemoved(i)
        }
    }
```

This is my function where i am getting listOtdeleteItem Position which we have delete from adapter (like we have 10 item in list then we need delete 1,7,9 ) but when i try to delete then its delete only 1 item not other can any one help me what i am doing wrong how we can delete multiple selected Position item from adapter one at a time

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil)

Comment: But i am unable get clear how we can delete list of item from adapter

Comment: Try this way
`for (i in listOfDeleteItemPosition.indices) {
            items.removeAt(i)  }
notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: but ui is not refreshing when it ry to remove its removing from listOfdatabut not from adapter item view

Comment: Can you post full code of adapter?

Answer (score 1):

If problem occurred due to position, to avoid the problem - just reverse the direction of for loop, so the code is like this:

```
        for (n in items.size downTo 0) {
            items.removeAt(n)
            notifyItemRemoved(n)
        }
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: is there any exception you can see while executing the delete process?